# How to save a value from a column after searching for a particular record in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to search for a record using values in two columns of a table, but then save a value from another column of this same record as a variable. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE CourseName = 'Psych101' AND FY = '2020'
```

There is another column called "CourseID", so what I need to do is find the course using the simple query above, then capture the value in the CourseID column and save it as a variable to call later on in a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like you are looking for one specific record, you can `DECLARE` a variable in sql-server.

A quick example to declare a variable and store a value

```
DECLARE @PyschCourseID (REPLACE WITH TYPE OF COURSEID)

SELECT @PyschCourseID = CourseID
FROM   Courses
WHERE  CourseName = 'Psych101' AND FY = '2020'
```

However, if you are only using this value once, I would recommend a `JOIN` on the [Courses] table if some *foreign key* relationship exists. For example:

```
UPDATE TableB
SET Col = @newValue
FROM TableB B
JOIN Courses c ON c.CourseID = B.CourseID
WHERE  c.CourseName = 'Psych101' AND c.FY = '2020'
```